# How to add data from other table to a double single table MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have this functional query:

`SELECT t1.material, t1.totalS, t2.totalH, (t1.totalS + t2.totalH) as producto, t1.fecha_dbfS, t2.fecha_dbfH FROM (SELECT material, STR_TO_DATE(fe_contab, '%d-%m-%Y') AS fecha_dbfS, SUM(impteml) AS TotalS FROM datos WHERE d_h ='S' GROUP BY material) as t1, (SELECT material, STR_TO_DATE(fe_contab, '%d-%m-%Y') AS fecha_dbfH, SUM(impteml) AS TotalH FROM datos WHERE d_h ='H' GROUP BY material) as t2 WHERE t1.material = t2.material and t1.fecha_dbfS >= '$fechai'and t1.fecha_dbfS <= '$fechaf' and t2.fecha_dbfH >= '$fechai' and t2.fecha_dbfH <= '$fechaf'`

That display data like this (DTR = material) [Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTMXs.png)

And i have another table named nombre_dtr, it has the data arranged like this:

[nombre_dtr table data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQZRt.png)

I need to add to the first table (Result of the query) the name of the DTR that it's stored on the nombre_dtr table as "nombre", using the DTR field on that table to math the "material" field on the "datos" table, i tried left and inner join but no luck.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can actually simplify your query by using aggregate function with case statement and join table `nombre_dtr` to get column `nombre` by each `material`

```
SELECT  d.material,
        n.nombre,
        SUM(CASE WHEN d.d_h = 'S' THEN d.impteml ELSE 0 END) AS TotalS,
        SUM(CASE WHEN d.d_h = 'H' THEN d.impteml ELSE 0 END) AS TotalH,
        SUM(d.impteml) AS producto,
        MAX(CASE WHEN d.d_h = 'S' THEN STR_TO_DATE(d.fe_contab, '%d-%m-%Y') END) fecha_dbfS,
        MAX(CASE WHEN d.d_h = 'H' THEN STR_TO_DATE(d.fe_contab, '%d-%m-%Y') END) fecha_dbfH
FROM    datos d
        INNER JOIN nombre_dtr n
            ON d.material = n.dtr
WHERE   STR_TO_DATE(d.fe_contab, '%d-%m-%Y') >= '$fechai'
        AND STR_TO_DATE(d.fe_contab, '%d-%m-%Y') <= '$fechaf' 
GROUP   BY d.material, n.nombre
```

Here's a guide about [SQL Join](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/).

Comment: I'm gonna try this in a couple of hours, thanks in advance mate.

Comment: Didn't work, tried on phpmyadmin (I'm using MAMP to test) and it never ends, used a example short date range instead of $fechai $fechaf